# Does disabling TeamCity built-in authentication remove saved passwords?

Tags: teamcity

I've added Azure AD integration to TeamCity and want to disable the built-in authentication to force users to authenticate via AAD/O365.  Most accounts have corresponding AAD accounts, but there are a few non-integrated accounts I want to keep local because they don't correspond to actual users.

If I remove the built-in authentication option, will the password data for non-integrated accounts be preserved or deleted?  I want to be able to re-enable local auth and sign in as one of the headless accounts if ever needed, but am afraid of getting locked out of those accounts.

Please point me to some documentation if possible.  I've had trouble finding any on this specific question.